# Getting system audio

Tags: java, audio

I have to get the system audio (the mixer). I tried this:

```
Mixer.Info[] info = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    try {
        for(Mixer.Info i : info) {
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(i);
            Line.Info[] linesInfo = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
            for(Line.Info lineInfo : linesInfo) {
                Line line = mixer.getLine(lineInfo);
                line.open();

                if(line.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME)) {
                    FloatControl control = (FloatControl) line.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
                    System.out.println(control.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but it throws LineUnavailableException(s):

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:413)
```

If necessary I can use external libraries.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you just want to play a sound, you don’t need to locate a TargetDataLine, you can just open a [Clip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getClip--).

Comment: I want to get the "processes" of the mixer and their intensity (dB) @VGR